# Image files upload to AWS S3 Bucket, but don't render on django heroku App

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a Django webapp that is hosted on Heroku. The site functions perfectly except or the image rendering. I am using AWS S3 buckets.

How my images currently look.

[image]

**This is the output when right click and view image in a new tab**

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document 

tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
<RequestId>B965F49FC9AD8BD8</RequestId>
<HostId>
NyDkC2+pLPd/5tzWgJb+dEJOWu7eNCfbVyqLdZWOr1JyIFTe6rZ8BbRJHlbweCLU1MJ7xmlrxEM=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
# (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_cleanup',
    'taggit',
    'hitcount',
    'storages',
]

***************
***************


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I have no idea why it is doing this and have tried almost everything. I hope it is just a simple mistake!

Comment: Try to work out if you can configure signature v4 for S3 access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error.. like you said its very tiny detail..

-for the above error add the lines below to settings.py

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1' #change to your region
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
```

Cheers, have a great day!

Comment: i did the same but it's not working why?